# java android new String

Tags: java, android, string, api

I have to convert a byte array to a string. Therefore I use this function:

```
public static String byteToString(byte[] bytes) {
    String str = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF8"));

    return str;
}
```

The problem is, that it requires API 9:

`Call requires API level 9 (current min is 8): new java.lang.String`

but I want to provide my app to API 8 users too. Is there any possibility or alternative?

Comment: Which call?  The forName?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the String constructor with the Charset paramter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`new String(bytes, "UTF8")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.lang.String%29) (The constructor `String(byte[], String)`). It's always available (API level 1+).

Comment: Yup: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. What you can do is to check for the `sdk` version

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
    // Constructor with charset
  } else {
   // Constructor without charset, providing the charset as string
  }
```

[Froyo](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) devices are something like `0.7%`

Comment: As there is a [constructor with a charset argument](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.lang.String%29) for that API level, this is a somewhat bad answer, isn't it?

Comment: no it is not (imo). He can use the check to call different constructors, avoid an additional call - I didn't check the framework code - but he will probably avoid an additional, internal `this(....)` call. In any case it will not harm, @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: Technically there is no Constructor for Charset object but for String charSet on API 8 (Still I would use this kind of check)

Comment: I see your point, but I referred to the comment `//Constructor without charset`. This is a bad advice, as it might not produce the same string as the other one. In fact, he always should provide the charset, either as an object or by name.

Comment: yah sorry, it was just wording. What I meant was  // Constructor without charset, providing the charset as string. Thanks @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: Comments are always _about wording_ and I tend to be a bit pedantic on such things as comments and namings, etc. Now it's a good answer, by the way. +1

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it's working well. But I gave +1 too for your help, thank you